# Array of Sumproduct using only one if statement

Tags: arrays, if-statement, excel-formula, product

I'd like to create a formula that creates multiple arrays based on an if statement, multiplies the arrays, and then sums the products.

So if these are my arrays:
[image]

I'd like to sum their product if A doesn't equal 0. My current formula works, but I'd like to be able to do this with only one if statement.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A1:A5<>"",A1:A5%),IF(A1:A5<>"",B1:B5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A5<>"",(A1:A5%*B1:B5)))
```

...which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.